# Can I create a SOAP webservice (ASMX) with .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asmx, .net-4.8

I am not very experienced with .NET development, and I often work on legacy integration projects that require me to deal with .NET SOAP webservices.

I know it's fairly trivial to build a SOAP service with .NET Framework 4. It even presents a nice page to test the service when you hit the .asmx endpoint using a browser.

Now, I wonder if it's possible to develop the same kind of service with .NET Core or .NET 5, 6.

Comment: See this articles :
https://medium.com/@duncan.osindi/create-soap-web-service-in-dotnet-core-4df801261484  or https://medium.com/compendium/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb

Comment: I had so much trouble with SoapCore I'd recommend using the good old .net481 one, except you dont need to generate a server based on a WSDL contract. In my case Data annotations did not work, even the generator for .net core did leave blanks I had to fill manually